# Show images from Amazon S3 private bucket in frontend using Node js Vue js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, amazon-s3

i tried getting the Buffer from Amazon S3 image then i converted into base64 string and sent to the frontend.
It worked well, it shows the image in the page, but the problem is the long time of proccesing base64.
How to make a workaround which will be much faster than base64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate s3 signed URL link for each image and send the links to the front end. Now, the front end can make respective calls to fetch all images.

This will reduce the time that backend does for the processing.

Comment: in this case the bucket must be public for anyone and that s not what i want

Comment: No, signed url can be generated for private objects. Need not make the bucket public.